# Changing checkbox attributes for multiple rows with single checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Good Morning,

Im working on a larger project but i tried to do a simple page in order to check my work. php/mysql newb here. Sorry! :)

What im trying to accomplish is ultimately having a single user page shown with rows of tasks from a table and a single check mark in order to say if the user has completed the task or not by checking or unchecking the box.

For testing purposes, I have set up a table with rows labled testid, testdata and testcheck. The testid a INT(2)AutoIncrement and Primary and Unique, testdata is a VARCHAR(30) and testcheck is a TINYINT(1). The auto increment isnt really important because I manually populated all the rows. I have 5 rows (for the array sake) consisting of 1-5 testid, "testdata1-5" for testdata and either a 0 or a 1 for testcheck. The table is functioning fine and the database can be queried.

Here is the code for the php start page:

```
<html>

<?php

include_once('init.php');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT testid, testdata, testcheck FROM testtable");

?>
<h1>Test form for checkmarks</h1>
<form method="POST" action="testover.php">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Test ID
        </td>
        <td>
            Test Data
        </td>
        <td>
            Checked
        </td>
        <td>
            Test Check
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
?>            
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['testid']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['testdata']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <center><input type="checkbox" name="<?php $row['testid'] ?>" value="<?php $row['testcheck']; ?>" <?php if($row['testcheck']=='1'){echo 'checked';} ?>></center>
        </td>
        <td>
            <center><?php echo $row['testcheck']; ?></center>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
           <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm Details">
           <a href="testcheck.php"><input type="button" value="Home"></a>
</form>
</html>
```

Ive been going back and forth trying to use an array for the inputs name (name="something[]") or the "isset" parameter but that is where my knowledge is failing. Ive read countless articles both here and on other websites and I cant seem to find the right code to use. Most sites have rows with multiple check boxes or a different layout of their table.

I posted here to hopefully be pointed in some direction as to how to update the DB with these values of the check marks.

Comment: You lack the `<form></form>` tag. the submit button requires a form to work and send the data through to the page you'd like or the refresh and use that data. Even if it's just a simple checkbox. After that you can use the `if(isset())` part, cause your submit button doesn't know what to submit.

Comment: I edited it so they are easier to see but they were in the original.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to make sense of your code on what you want, and if I understand it right, you want those 5 rows outputted right?

```
<?php 
echo '<form action=''>;
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['testid']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['testdata']."</td>";
echo "<td><input='checkbox' name='".$row['testid']."' value='".$row['testcheck']."'  ".if($row['testcheck']=='1'){echo 'checked';}."></td>";
echo "<td>".$row['testcheck']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' name='confirm'>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

and then updating. since the form has no action, it returns to itself. So now you can add on top of your page your new php and updating code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['confirm'])){ // the name of your submit button
    // your update code here.
?>
```

-- edit --

[Checkbox looping in php while posting to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724994/checkbox-looping-in-php-while-posting-to-database)

I had a while ago the same problem as you. I needed to loop through checkboxes to post. Please check this topic for relevant information.

Comment: The 5 rows output correctly. They show the testid, testdata and testcheck columns from the table including the check mark. I would like for the submission process to update any changes to the check marks in their appropriate rows in the table.

Comment: okay, as i stated in my answer, it requires to be then in a `form` so when you press the submit button, it knows it has to POST the data within the form. In the `action` attribute of the `form` you can specify where your script is (blank is on the same page). Then add an isset as i stated above your call to the update.

Comment: I used your code (had to take the input line out of PHP; netbeans didnt like it at all) but im probably messing up on the update line. I also do not know how to add code to comments here.... ugh

Comment: its because i made an error in the quotation ;) it's `"<input type='submit' name='confirm'>";` i fixed that line here :) and will do it in the answer as well. the isset code is a bit more complicated, but what you need to do is make sure it checks which checkboxes are checked and that it executes the update statements on there. I ll see if i can post an example

Comment: i actually meant the input line above where the checkboxes are being made

Comment: `value='".$row['testcheck']."'` instead of `value='".$row['testcheck'];."'` .. my bad ... a `;` to much. I copied your code over to edit quickly. Anyway, updated the answer again.

Comment: unexpected if after. - regardless its fine with the code i wrote. Ill look through that link you posted above. Its very complicated but i hope to step through it slowly. It look like exactly what im doing so hopefully it will work out.

Comment: I cant follow from what you had coded to what CodeBird offered as a change. I would need to see the final result in order to read down through the code to try to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is my new code. I know im on the right track. Just need some guidance in writing the isset statement and such.

```
<?php

include_once('init.php');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT testid, testdata, testcheck FROM testtable");

$checkedarray = $_POST['isChecked'];

if(isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
if(isset($checkedarray)){ // the name of your submit button
   foreach ($checkedarray as $value)
mysql_query("UPDATE testtable SET testcheck = '{$value}' WHERE testid = {$_POST['testid']}"); } }
?>

<h1>Test form for checkmarks</h1>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
 <td>
            Test ID
        </td>
        <td>
            Test Data
        </td>
        <td>
            Checked
        </td>
        <td>
            Test Check
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php 
echo '<form action="">';
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['testid']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['testdata']."</td>"; ?>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="isChecked[]" value="<?php $row['testcheck']; ?>" <?php if($row['testcheck']=='1'){echo 'checked';} ?>></td>
<?php
echo "<td>".$row['testcheck']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' name='confirm'>";
echo "</form>";
?>
           <a href="testcheck.php"><input type="button" value="Home"></a>
</form>
</html>
```